# Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded (unable to determine cause of infinite loop)

Tags: python, loops, recursion, limit

hopefully someone out there can make sense of what is likely some very messed up code. I am slowly getting into python in my free time and decided to make a tic tac toe game.

the problem is that toward the end of the game, if the human player does not win, the computer's turn function goes into an infinite loop and crashes the code.

Code:

```
import random
board = [[' ',' ',' ',],[' ',' ',' ',],[' ',' ',' ',]]

def printboard():
    spacercount = 0
    print "    |     |  "
    for row in board:
        print row[0] + "   | " + row[1] + "   | " + row[2]
        if spacercount < 2:
            print "---------------"
            print "    |     |  "
            spacercount += 1
    print "\n"
    print "____________________ \n \n"


def userturn():
    x = raw_input("Choose row: ")
    y = raw_input("Choose column: ")
    print "\n"
    if board[int(x)][int(y)] == " ":
        board[int(x)][int(y)] = "X"
        printboard()
        if checkwin("X") == True:
            print "player has won!"
        elif checkfull() == True:
            print "it's a tie!"
        else:
            computerturn()
    else:
        print "this space is already taken, try again"
        userturn()

def computerturn():
    x = random.randint(1,2)
    y = random.randint(1,2)
    print "\n"
    if board[int(x)][int(y)] == " ":
        board[int(x)][int(y)] = "O"
        printboard()
        if checkwin("O") == True:
            print "computer has won!"
        elif checkfull() == True:
            print "it's a tie!"
        else:
            userturn()
    else:
        computerturn()

def checkwin(le):
    return ((board[0][2] == le and board[1][1] == le and board[2][0] == le) or
    (board[0][0] == le and board[1][1] == le and board[2][2] == le) or
    (board[0][0] == le and board[1][0] == le and board[2][0] == le) or
    (board[0][1] == le and board[1][1] == le and board[2][1] == le) or
    (board[0][2] == le and board[1][2] == le and board[2][2] == le) or
    (board[0][0] == le and board[0][1] == le and board[0][2] == le) or
    (board[1][0] == le and board[1][1] == le and board[1][2] == le) or
    (board[2][0] == le and board[2][1] == le and board[2][2] == le))

def checkfull():
    for x in board:
        if x[0] != " " and x[1] != " " and x[2] != " ":
            return True
        else:
            return False

printboard()
userturn()
```

I must have gone through the computerturn function a hundred times trying to determine why an infinite loop is started, but have not been successful.

any help greatly appreciated :) hopefully the code is straightforward enough that comments are not needed but if so i will add them in

Comment: First, `random.randint(1,2)` already returns an `int`, so you don't have to cast it again with `int()`. Second, whenever `board[1][1]`, `board[1][2]`, `board[2][1]`, and `board[2][2]` contain something other than `' '`, the function has no option but to call itself again repeatedly until producing the error you saw. You need to take another look at the conditions that halt the recursion.

Comment: __How__ does it crash the code?

Answer (score 1):

First, your empty `board`:

```
board = [[' ',' ',' ',],[' ',' ',' ',],[' ',' ',' ',]]
```

A single space character denotes an empty square.

Next, the first thing your program does after printing the board is call `userturn()`. The user makes some kind of move, and, if it succeeds, the program calls `computerturn()`. But, how does the computer move?

It looks for empty squares in part of the board (not all of it - only the second and third columns and rows because of `randint(1,2)` instead of `randint(0,2)`). If the randomly-selected square is occupied, the computer tries to go again. Once all of the squares it checks are occupied, it will never be able to do anything but try to go again. It will then do so repeatedly until it's stopped by the maximum recursion depth.

How do we fix this? Instead of having the computer repeatedly pick a random move from the entire board and making it keep trying until it picks a valid move, we'll limit its moves to the ones that are actually available.

```
def computerturn():
    available = [(x, y) for x,row in enumerate(board)
                 for y,column in enumerate(row)
                 if board[x][y] == ' ']
                # this is a list of actual available moves
    x,y = random.choice() # select from actual available moves
    # x = random.randint(0,2) # don't want this
    # y = random.randint(0,2) # don't want this
    print "\n"
    # don't need the following conditional
    #if board[x][y] == " ": # don't need the int() calls
    board[x][y] = "O" # this is the only thing that a successful move should do
    printboard() # unindent all this stuff
    if checkwin("O"): # don't need to compare a Boolean to True
        print "computer has won!"
    elif checkfull():
        print "it's a tie!"
    else:
        userturn()

    #else: # let's just take out this whole recursive call and fix the random move
    #    computerturn()
```

And now a "clean" version with the comments and obsolete code removed:

```
def computerturn():
    available = [(x, y) for x,row in enumerate(board)
                 for y,column in enumerate(row)
                 if board[x][y] == ' ']
    x,y = random.choice()
    print "\n"
    board[x][y] = "O"
    printboard()
    if checkwin("O"):
        print "computer has won!"
    elif checkfull():
        print "it's a tie!"
    else:
        userturn()
```

We [hardly even need the comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) - you can see what's going on from the code itself.

Comment: thanks a lot, looks like i need to brush up on list comprehension